# Modifying a class variable with a method within the class in Java

Tags: reference, insert, binary-search-tree, pass-by-reference

The code below inserts new nodes in a Binary Search Tree.

When I'm creating an object of the class *BinarySearchTree*, in the driver function, and using its *insert* function for the first time, the *root* gets updated. This is how it should be too, since we are setting the *root* to be *newNode*.

But if we use the insert function of the same object thereafter, the *root* is not *null* anymore and only the currentNode variable within the function gets worked upon, after being set equal to *root*. The variable *root* of the object isn't being changed or worked upon, at all.

So why does the insert function, after its first use, is able to build the BST by adding nodes as the children of the *root* variable of the object?

```
public class BinarySearchTree {

    class BSTNode {

        public int value;
        public BSTNode left;
        public BSTNode right;
    }


    BSTNode root;

    BinarySearchTree () {
        root = null;
    }



    //Insert
    public void insert(int val) {

        BSTNode newNode = new BSTNode();
        newNode.value = val;

        if (root==null) {
            root = newNode;                //Root gets updated
            return;
        }

        BSTNode currentNode = root;        //currentNode will be worked upon

        while (true) {

            if (val <= currentNode.value) {

                if (currentNode.left==null) {
                    currentNode.left = newNode;
                    return;
                }

                currentNode = currentNode.left;
            }

            else {

                if (currentNode.right==null) {
                    currentNode.right = newNode;
                    return;
                }

                currentNode = currentNode.right;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to visualise what happens when a second value is inserted -- so in a tree that currently has one node, i.e. the root. Let's say we have this driver code:

```java
BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
tree.insert(5);
tree.insert(2);
```

At the start of the second `insert` execution, we have this situation:

```
tree
  ↓
┌─BinarySearchTree─┐   ┌─BSTNode─────┐
│                  │   │ val: 5      │
│ root: ──────────────►│ left: null  │
└──────────────────┘   │ right: null │ 
                       └─────────────┘
```

First, `newNode` is created and given a value -- it has no dependency with the tree yet -- and `currentNode` is assigned the same *reference* as `root`:

```
tree                    currentNode       newNode
  ↓                       ↓                 ↓
┌─BinarySearchTree─┐   ┌─BSTNode─────┐   ┌─BSTNode─────┐
│                  │   │ val: 5      │   │ val: 2      │
│ root: ──────────────►│ left: null  │   │ left: null  │
└──────────────────┘   │ right: null │   │ right: null │
                       └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
```

Note how `root` and `currentNode` reference the same `BSTNode` instance, but also that these variables (`root` is a field), have their own memory for their references.

In the first iteration of the loop, this statement will be executed in the first `if` block:

```
currentNode.left = newNode;
```

Which mutates the single node that both `currentNode` and `root` reference. We get:

```
tree                    currentNode       newNode
  ↓                       ↓                 ↓
┌─BinarySearchTree─┐   ┌─BSTNode─────┐   ┌─BSTNode─────┐
│                  │   │ val: 5      │   │ val: 2      │
│ root: ──────────────►│ left: ────────► │ left: null  │
└──────────────────┘   │ right: null │   │ right: null │
                       └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
```

And in the next statement, `currentNode` will be reassigned a new reference -- following the one that was assigned to the `left` field, and so we get:

```
tree                                  currentNode  newNode
  ↓                                        ↓         ↓
┌─BinarySearchTree─┐   ┌─BSTNode─────┐   ┌─BSTNode─────┐
│                  │   │ val: 5      │   │ val: 2      │
│ root: ──────────────►│ left: ────────► │ left: null  │
└──────────────────┘   │ right: null │   │ right: null │
                       └─────────────┘   └─────────────┘
```

Note that an assignment to a variable (not a field), will never mutate an object. It just affects that variable itself.

Hope this clarifies it.